# How to assign value to jenkins node using a value from a property file

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

I am able to load a property file in Jenkins declarative pipeline. On echo, the values get printed too, in the console output. I want to use one of the values in the property file, say slavenode, as Jenkins label. However, I am not able to do so. I have tried following, but it fails :

```
stage ('echo variables'){
            agent {label 'a_server_name'}
            steps{
              load "path_to_file\\abc.properties"

                echo "Hi"
                echo "slave : ${SlaveNode}"

                              //executes successfully

            }

stage ('Execute script'){
            agent {label "$SlaveNode"}
            steps{
                echo "This is executing script"

            }

  // fails with error : There are no nodes with the label ‘SlaveNode’
```

I want it to run the 'execute script' stage on $SlaveNode.

Comment: I think that agent labels need to be established at initialization, which would make this dynamic runtime labeling impossible, but I may be wrong.

Comment: I found a solution to it and it worked!!.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can do this using Groovy Library and environment variables

Comment: I don't want to use environment variable. As the property file gets updated by some other script, the values change. Hence, I want to use the updated property file to select the node on which it is to be run further.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code which worked for me :

```
  steps{
      node( SlaveNode as String )
        { sh """ echo "It is running on SlaveNode" """ }
    }
```